# IntelliJ IDEA - Multi-monitor window management

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, multiple-monitors, multi-window

I am using `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2` with a Dual monitor setup as shown in the image below. (Arranged side by side one portrait and other landscape as usual)

I have 2 Issues

**Issue no. 1**

I want to split my all `.xml` by default to split mode in a way that the design should appear on one monitor (Monitor 1 as per image) and the code should appear on the other (Monitor 2 as per image). I can't find a way to split the design window that way. (Of course I an right click on any window and use `View mode > Window` ) But this will not make the **Design** and **Code** windows split into 2 separate windows.

**Issue no. 2**

Assume that I've taken Logcat to a separate window and that window is moved to 2nd monitor. (Or any other component for that matter). How to make Android Studio aware of my window arrangement preferences for all the projects I work on. If I restart my PC the window arrangement is not retained (Logcat may appear in a separate window but not in the right monitor) Also if I open a new project all of the preferences are ignored altogether and each component comes in the default `Dock Pinned` View Mode.

How to fix these, Any suggestion would help[image]

Comment: For future readers: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166033/IntelliJ-IDEA-doesnt-remember-position-on-multi-screen-display

Answer (score 1):

**Issue no. 1**

You can try the following approach:

- Open layout XML file in the editor twice. The first tab should be opened in `Code` mode and the second one in `Design`
- Right click on one of these editor tabs and select `Move Tab to New Window`
- Move the window to another screen

[image]

**Issue no. 2**

Try using `Window | Layouts | Save Changes in Current Layout` or `Window | Layouts | Save Current Layout as New` after arranging tool windows

Comment: This way splits the code and design into 2 windows but my actions are not reflected in real-time. Example: If a add/delete or modify any view in XML code my Design does not get updated instantly. I have to click on design and perform any action to see my changes. vice-a-versa is also true. If there is a way to auto-refresh the design/code window this can be a great workaround.